# How to edit website homepage without adding a file

Tags: html, web

I would like to edit the text on my new website, without adding the file as a link, which takes you to a page with the html output. How should I go about this? Add the file as an html document to the public folder?

If it makes any difference the site is hosted on Hostgator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i dont really understand what you are trying to do, but it seems to me that you would want to put a div or an iframe in your main page and load the other page's html into those.